# Execute rustfmt on file save in IntelliJ or CLion

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, ide, clion, rustfmt

How do I run `rustfmt` automatically when I save a file in IntelliJ or CLion?

Answer (score 22):

It should be noted that while bit2pixel's answer will work, (and indeed is how I did it for a good long while), there's a newer (better?) way.  The rust-plugin has an option to handle this automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you have `File Watchers` plugin via `Preferences -> Plugins -> Installed`. If it's not installed, go to the `Marketplace` tab and search for `File Watchers`, install it, and restart your IDE.
2. Go to `Preferences -> Tools -> File Watchers`.

   [image: File Watchers]
3. Add a new watcher and name it `rustfmt`.

   [image: File Watchers]
4. Configure the watcher by following the screenshot below. Enter the path to `rustfmt` into the `Program` field; it can be found in your `Cargo bin directory`.

> If you don't know where `Cargo bin directory` directory is, type `which rustfmt` in your terminal and copy the path. If you still can't find it, make sure you followed the instructions in [Installing Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html).

[image]

Comment: You can add `$FILE_PATH$:$LINE$:$COLUMN$` to "Output filters" to get line highlighting too. Can optionally set "show console" to never if you only want to see line highlighting on errors and not the console output.

Note that you can also run rustfmt using a setting in the rust plugin now, but it's been buggy lately so I've been using this instead.